# Implement binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

This is my binary-search:

```
int binarySearch(int arr[], int value, int min, int max){
  int pos = -1;

  while (max >= min && pos == -1) {
    int mid = (max+min)/2;

    if(arr[mid] ==  value){
      pos = mid;
    }else if(arr[mid] < value){
      min = mid +1;
    }else if(arr[mid] > value){
      max = mid -1;
    }

  }
  return pos;
}
```

I call it this way:

```
 //Arr contain values 0-63
int i = binarySearch(arr, 64, 0, 64);
```

These are the mid values

```
32 48 56 60 62 63 64
```

At the last check I try to access an element at pos 64, when the last position in the array is 63.

What's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: I suggest stepping through the code in a debugger, line by line, while checking the values of `max`, `min` and `mid`. Also make sure the array is actually sorted.

Comment: The code runs fine with me on code blocks.
Make sure the array is sorted and contains exactly 64 elements

Comment: -1 for dumping your link in chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Array contains values from 0-63 (as you mentioned) and you are giving following values for min and max: min=0, max=64. And change the following line so that your code can handle high int values otherwise there are chances of memory overflow.

```
       int mid = min+(max-min)/2;
```

The above formula simplifies to (max+min)/2 itself but protect integer overflow.

Comment: Its unnecessary.
Try running with both the versions.

Comment: @CodingMash: well, this would make sense if your indexes were enormous. But you would hardly be able to allocate an array that large in practice.

Answer (score 0):

When max==min, your length is 0, so you shouldn't be going into the loop.  Change while condition to `(max > min && ...)` if your high-water is "one past the end" (and your high water should probably be "one past the end", it is a really useful pattern)

Oh, and make it `max = mid` instead of `max = mid-1`, as max represents "one beyond the end" rather than the last element.

As a general coding style improvement, when doing this kind of code, toss asserts all over the place that your indexes are within bounds.  This can not only catch problems earlier, it can also help you reason about what values are in bounds and which are not...

Comment: If I do max > min I will never be able to find anything at position 0 in the array.

Comment: When `max = 1` and `min = 0`, what is `mid`?  There are two problems in your code, both related to the meaning of `max`.  I'm advising you to say that the indexes to search through are {`min`, `min+1`, `min+2`, ... , `max-2`, `max-1`}: `max` is "one past the last index to search through".  This lines up with passing `64` in as `max` to start with.  However, to fix this, when you find that the value at `mid` is too large, the search range should be [`min`, `mid`) not [`min`, `mid-1`).  (I'm using [a,b) to denote the half-open interval between a and b, which doesn't include b)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
while (max > min && pos == -1) {
    int mid = (max+min)/2;

    if(arr[mid] ==  value){
        pos = mid;
    }else if(arr[mid] < value){
        min = mid;
    }else if(arr[mid] > value){
        max = mid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not appreciated in SO.

Comment: Then I can't access the first element.